# Unexpected if/else results using booleans

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean

I'm setting up some simple booleans that test for mobile layouts and touch devices, but I'm having some difficulty making the code more compact.

`isTouch` tests for touch devices.

`mobile` tests for when the screen width is below 769px.

My final `if/else` statement is to test if I'm on a mobile touch device (iPad, phone, whatever). I can alert the output and everything is expected, but the `static_element` still appears instead of `swiper_element`. I know I'm missing something with my booleans.

Help a rookie out?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var windowWidth,
        isTouch = (('ontouchstart' in window) || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0)),
        mobile,
        touchDevice;

    $(window).on('load resize', function () {
        windowWidth = $(window).width();

        if (windowWidth < 769) {
            mobile = true;
        } else {
            mobile = false;
        }

        if (isTouch = true) {
            touchDevice = true;
        } else {
            touchDevice = false;
        }
    });

    if (touchDevice && mobile) {
        $('.static_element').hide();
        $('.swiper_element').show();
    } else {
        $('.static_element').show();
        $('.swiper-element').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Typo in your if block: `'=' != '=='`. But you can simplify that to just `if (isTouch) …` or even better eliminate the `isTouch` variable and the if block entirely and assign the value `touchDevice` directly.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Which if block? So, it should be `if (isTouch == true) { ... }`?

Comment: That would work, or the other suggestions I mentioned.

Comment: The code block `if (windowWidth < 769) { mobile = true; } else { mobile = false; }` can be simplified to `mobile = (windowWidth <  769);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swiper thing is not working, because there is a dash instead of an underscore in the last line of your code. And yes, you could simplify a few things (see the code below). I moved all mobile detection logic to a function, so we can reuse it anytime we want.

**Note:** Mobile detection is an art – mainly because there are many devices and use cases. Querying the "ontouchstart" capability works fine for most of the devices, it won't work on some devices. That's why I added the `console.log`, so you can check if the right code block is executed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isTouch,
        isMobile;

    // Initially call the function to set isTouch and isMobie 
    detectMobile();

    // If the window is reloaded or resized check again
    $(window).on('load resize', detectMobile);


    // Set the booleans when called
    function detectMobile() {
        // Always evalutes to true or false
        isTouch = ('ontouchstart' in window) || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0);
        // Always evalutes to true or false
        isMobile = $(window).width() < 769;
    }

    if (isTouch && isMobile) {
        // Logs the actual status to the console
        console.log("I'm a mobile device!");
        $('.static_element').hide();
        $('.swiper_element').show();
    } else {
        // Logs the actual status to the console 
        console.log("I'm a boring normal device!");
        $('.static_element').show();
        $('.swiper_element').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your codes into this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var windowWidth,
    isTouch = (('ontouchstart' in window) || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0)),
    mobile,
    touchDevice;

$(window).on('load resize', function () {
    windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if (windowWidth < 769) {
        mobile = true;
    } else {
        mobile = false;
    }

    if (isTouch) {
        touchDevice = true;
    } else {
        touchDevice = false;
    }
});

if (touchDevice && mobile) {
    $('.static_element').hide();
    $('.swiper_element').show();
} else {
    $('.static_element').show();
    $('.swiper-element').hide();
}
});
```